# Does the webcomponentsjs library support Internet Explorer 9?

Tags: polymer-1.0

webcomponents-lite.min.js - does this support IE9? I am not getting positive result while running Polymer-starter-kit. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internet Explorer 9 is not mentioned in [browser support matrix](https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs#browser-support) provided in the official readme. The earliest version of IE mentioned is 10.

Thus, I think it would be safe to assume that IE 9 is **not** supported.